# jquery - add class to existing div with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a class to an existing div that has multiple classes but doesn't work, the class is not added.
I've added this on header (it's s shopify template):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('div.wk_right_header_inner wk_font_weight_bold wk_font_family wk_paddingbottom10').addClass('new-class');
 });
 </script>
```

The div looks like this (with no space after <):

```
<div class="wk_right_header_inner wk_font_weight_bold wk_font_family  
 wk_paddingbottom10"> Test </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: your selector syntax is wrong. And there's no need to use all the classes `$('div.wk_right_header_inner').addClass('new-class');
 });` is quite enough.

Comment: Yes, just pick one class name and `addClass` to that. Like: `$('div .wk_right_header_inner').addClass('new-class');`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to give it an ID and use `$('#id').addClass('new-class')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
$('div.wk_right_header_inner.wk_font_weight_bold.wk_font_family.wk_paddingbottom10').addClass('new-class');
 });
```

Because now it thinks the other classes are sub elements.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look a this:

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(' .wk_right_header_inner ').addClass('new-class');
 });
```

```css
.new-class
{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wk_right_header_inner wk_font_weight_bold wk_font_family wk_paddingbottom10"> Test </div>
```

Comment: @johnstoe Glad that it helped you!